# How to get the value from another field when press the button save

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

- i have created a customize module to change the selling price because
  i want the selling price to depend on the price of the supplier.
- My problem is how to put the allocation of the value of the supplier price **(price)** in the price field (list_price) is made when clicking the save button after the creation of a new product because I noticed that the field "list_price" takes the value of the field "price" just after clicking on the button create a new product it means even before I enter the data of the field "price" (price of the supplier). In this way the value of the field "list_price" takes the value "0".
- Any idea for help please?

**product.py**

```
 from openerp import fields, models, api


 class product(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'product.template'

     product_tmpl_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product')
     list_price = fields.Float(string="Prix de vente", store=True, related='product_tmpl_id.seller_ids.price')
```

Comment: Did you override `create` method?

Comment: No i didn't override create methode

Comment: When you press `save` button for the first time it calls the `create` method otherwize it calls the `write` method, so you can override one method or both to get your value from where you want after calling `super`.

Comment: Thank you very much